# NavMenu doesn't render in ReactCrudDemo tutorial

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asp.net-core

I'm attempting to follow the ReactCrudDemo at https://dzone.com/articles/aspnet-core-crud-with-reactjs-and-entity-framework. The tutorial uses .NET Core 2 but I'm using .Net Core 3.1, so I'm encountering some differences I can't figure out how to fix. One is that my NavMenu isn't rendering properly (but the code exists in the DOM).

I'm stuck and don't know how to fix it. Can anyone help me out?

My application looks like:

[image]

It's supposed to look like:

[image]

This is the code from NavMenu.tsx:

```
import './NavMenu.css';    
import * as React from 'react';
import { Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

export class NavMenu extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
    public render() {
        return <div className='main-nav'>
            <div className='navbar navbar-inverse'>
                <div className='navbar-header'>
                    <button type='button' className='navbar-toggle' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='.navbar-collapse'>
                        <span className='sr-only'>Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span className='icon-bar'></span>
                        <span className='icon-bar'></span>
                        <span className='icon-bar'></span>
                    </button>
                    <Link className='navbar-brand' to={'/'}>ReactCrudDemo</Link>
                </div>
                <div className='clearfix'></div>
                <div className='navbar-collapse collapse'>
                    <ul className='nav navbar-nav'>
                        <li>
                            <NavLink to={'/'} exact activeClassName='active'>
                                <span className='glyphicon glyphicon-home'></span> Home
                            </NavLink>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <NavLink to={'/fetchemployee'} activeClassName='active'>
                                <span className='glyphicon glyphicon-th-list'></span> Fetch employee
                            </NavLink>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>;
    }
}
```

This is the code from Layout.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container } from 'reactstrap';
import { NavMenu } from './NavMenu';

export class Layout extends Component {
  static displayName = Layout.name;

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <NavMenu />
        <Container>
          {this.props.children}
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

My file structure is:

[image]

This shows the Network tab in DevTools
[image]

And this is the Sources tab. You can see that the NavMenu.tsx is loaded.
[image]

Comment: Nothing at all happens when I click on the NavMenu, and I don't get any errors in DevTools

Comment: Refresh with network tab open in dev tools. see if its making requests for your css js etc. and post results.

Comment: @JoeLloyd Thanks for looking! I've posted the Network and Sources tab. Do you see a cause?

Comment: yup, you never make a request for css. in the network tab you don't have any styling. thats why its not styled. you need to add it to your build process or static folder.